# How to enable "-fnative-double"?

Tags: swift3, metal

In my Metal Shader Source file, I want to use the type Double in my arguments, but it says "Use of type "double" requires the -fnative-double option to be enabled". How to enable this option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite that hopeful-sounding error message, Metal does not currently support double-precision floating-point.